# How to send data to view from controller AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to send data from api to my view... So I need to take data from get reqest and then send that data to my view on my page.

Here is my controller:

```
 angular.module('commentsApp',['notifications'])
           .config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
                $routeProvider.
                        when('/project/:id', {
                            controller: 'CommentsCtrl',
                            template: '<%comments%>'
                        }).
                        otherwise({
                            template: 'aaaaaaa',
                            redirectTo: '/'

                        });               

            })

          .controller('CommentsCtrl',function($scope,$http,$routeParams){
              $scope.comments = [];
              $scope.param = $routeParams.id;
              $http.get("/api/comments/"+ $scope.param)
              .success(function(data){
                   $scope.comments = data;       
              })
              .error(function(data){
                  console.log(data);
              });
          });
```

Here is my html:

```
<div id="comment" ng-app="commentsApp" class="panel-body">
                                <div ng-view>
                                    <h1><% ng %></h1> 
                                </div>


                            </div>
```

Comment: You mean you want to display the comments in your scope? I'm not sure what the issue is; if they're in scope you should be able to repeat over them or do whatever you want with them.

Answer (score 0):

You should be declaring your `ng-app` in the `<html>` tag.  I'm not sure what the `<% ng %>` is, nor the `<% comments %>` in your template, but that is not how angular renders data to the view. Since comments is an array, you'll want to use an `ng-repeat` to display the data.

Something like (in your template)

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="comment in comments">
    {{comment}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

The `{{comment}}` is how angular renders variables, similar to erb's `<%= comment %>`.  Comment, is a local variable for each `<li>` that gets generated by the `ng-repeat`, which gets its data from the $scope variable `comments`.

EDIT: Also you may need to `$scope.$apply();` in your CommentsController after you assign `$scope.comments = data`.  Not sure on this point, I haven't got angular's full digest cycle in my head yet.